# How float a div wrapper in html/css?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a vertical NavBar which is in a wrapper.  It works fine but the rest of my content follows below it.  I'd like to have the Vert Narbar on the Left maybe 20% width, and the content on the Right. I'll need to use a Clear for my footer.

**The Navbar CSS [omitting some unecessary lines] is:**

```css
div.wrapper {
  margin: 60px auto auto 8px;
  width: 220px;
}

p {
  /*4spaces*/
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 24px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.vertical>ul>li {
  display: block;
}

nav.vertical>ul>li>a {
  background-color: rgb(157, 34, 60);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  /*4spaces */
}

nav.vertical>ul>li>a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav.vertical>ul>li>div {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

nav.vertical>ul>li>div>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.vertical>ul>li>div>ul>li>a {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: #333331;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.35s linear;
}

nav.vertical>ul>li>div>ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px 0 10px 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 4 spaces  -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Category 1</a>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- 4 spaces  -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Category 2</a>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- 4 spaces  -->
</div>
<div style="padding-left:20px">
  <h1>Website Content Stuff</h1>

</div>

<!--  main content -->
<p>Ipsorum pro loekum text that we all hate</p>
```

I should mention that I got the Navbar code online from Adam-Bray

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Very nice, however, before embarking on a totally new CSS system I'd still like to see how I can format the Navbar left and the main content right.  I'd still have to figure out how to put my menu in the correct Grid or Flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a float on your `.wrapper` div, because it's a block element so it takes the full width and moves the content below it

Comment: Thanks very much!   I did it on the console by editing the element.style, and then I just added  **float:left;**  to my CSS code inside the **div.wrapper{ stuff }**.  I'll just add a **float:clear;** when I get to the footer.